# How to use Jackson JSON library to print everything in a json file, including nested array objects with no key and with objects in the array?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to print everything in a JSON file using Jackson in Java. I am 90% of the way there. Here is my Json File:

```
{
    "my-data": {
        "phone-number": "5555555555",
        "userId": "1234",
        "version": "2",
        "more-data": {
            "transaction-data": [
                {
                    "Merchant": "Walmart",
                    "authorized": "true",
                    "amount": "7.50",
                    "is_card_expired": false,
                    "credit_limit": "2000"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to print everything that has a key, but need help cleanly dealing with the array inside transaction-data. Notice that is an array with no key. Therefore, it is tricky to get inside, and my iterator (`Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> Iterator = node.fields()`) turns up empty. I cannot use `node.elements()`, because I need to get the key for everything, even if it is not something to print out. To print everything, my result should look something like

```
"phone-number": "5555555555"
"userId": "1234"
"version": "2"
"Merchant": "Walmart",
"authorized": "true",
"amount": "7.50",
"is_card_expired": false,
"credit_limit": "2000"
```

The best I have been able to come up with is after declaring my interator, I check if it hasNext(), and if not, then I create another iterator of elements (`Iterator<JsonNode> iterator2 = node.elements();`). While that has next I recursively call my method on each of the nodes inside that. This works, but I am not sure this is the best solution. How would you cleanly iterate through/traverse my JSON file to hit each and every node, regardless of if it is an object, an array, or a value node, and regardless of whether or not a key exists (if a key does not exist then I need not print it out, I just need to enter that container and print out the items inside of it

Comment: Seems like this question is the same as this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77291839/java-using-jackson-json-library-to-loop-recursive-through-any-jsondata) that you posted. At least this question has more details. Any reason why you posted another question rather than [edit]ing this one? Please refer to: [What happens when the same user asks the same question twice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425393/what-happens-when-the-same-user-asks-the-same-question-twice)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using standard recursive approach.
Where given entry is either a Object or Array of Objects.

Following link has exact same problem statement as yours:

[java using JSONObject to loop recursive through any jsondata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681496/java-using-jsonobject-to-loop-recursive-through-any-jsondata)

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to achieve the same with the Jackson library? Rather than org.Json?

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily do this with a JSON parser:

```java
JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(json);
JsonToken token = parser.nextToken();
while (token != null) {
    switch (token) {
        case VALUE_FALSE:
        case VALUE_TRUE:
            System.out.printf("\"%s\": %b%n", parser.currentName(), parser.getBooleanValue());
            break;
        case VALUE_NULL:
            System.out.printf("\"%s\": null%n", parser.currentName());
            break;
        case VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT:
        case VALUE_NUMBER_INT:
            System.out.printf("\"%s\": %d%n", parser.currentName(), parser.getNumberValue());
            break;
        case VALUE_STRING:
            System.out.printf("\"%s\": \"%s\"%n", parser.currentName(), parser.getText());
            break;
        default:
            // ignore
            break;
    }
    token = parser.nextToken();
}
```

The parser has a method called `currentValue()` but that doesn't work in the above example, it always returns `null`.